# How to parse Unix timestamp from JSON in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, timezone, timestamp, nsdate

I get timestamps from some RESTful services with this format:

```
"/Date(1357306469510+0100)/"
```

I found some posts providing code to parse this and create its equivalent `NSDate` object, for example:

```
NSInteger offset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
NSInteger startPosition = [jsonDate rangeOfString:@"("].location + 1;
NSTimeInterval unixTime = [[jsonDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPosition, 13)] doubleValue] / 1000;
NSDate *date = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTime] dateByAddingTimeInterval:offset];
```

but it does not seem to deal with the timezone of the server's timestamp (+0100).

Could somebody provide a complete solution, or tell me where could I find it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to display time zone or not?

Comment: @FawadMasud I need to take the timezone into account to have the correct time in `NSDate` object

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work. See my in-line comments for the explanation. Essentially, you have to figure out how many seconds from GMT that your server's time is offset by (in your case, `+3600` seconds).

```
//The date string
NSString *dStr = @"/Date(1357306469510+0100)/";

//Get the unix time
NSUInteger unixStart = [dStr rangeOfString:@"("].location + 1;
NSUInteger unixEnd = ([dStr rangeOfString:@"+"].location == NSNotFound ? [dStr rangeOfString:@"-"].location : [dStr rangeOfString:@"+"].location);
double unixTime = [[dStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(unixStart, unixEnd - unixStart)] doubleValue] / 1000;
NSLog(@"%f", unixTime);

//Get the timezone
NSUInteger tzStart = unixEnd;
NSUInteger tzEnd = [dStr rangeOfString:@")"].location;
float tzOffset = [[dStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(tzStart, tzEnd - tzStart)] floatValue] / 100 * 60 * 60;
NSLog(@"%f", tzOffset);

//Calculate the date
NSDate *date = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTime] dateByAddingTimeInterval:tzOffset];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I log the `NSDate` that I get from your code, `2015-02-09 07:52:25 +0000` is displayed, whereas logging `[NSDate date]` prints `2015-02-09 06:52:25 +0000`... I'd need to get either `2015-02-09 07:52:25 +0100` or `2015-02-09 06:52:25 +0000`

Comment: @AppsDev Are you sure the date you're inputting is correct? I tested it and it seemed to work for me... I used this site, got the unix timestamp, and put it into the string: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: It looks like the behaviour is correct... if I add the timezone's offset, I get the total of millisecs but I'm not "telling" the `NSDate` that such millisecs value is for +1 timezone, it considers +0 timezone... so I should tell some way the `NSDate` that its timezone is +1 if I provide it with the timezone's offset from JSON, or let the `NSDate`'s timezone remain +0 and not provide it the timezone's offset from JSON

Comment: @AppsDev What exactly is your end goal?

Comment: Having an `NSDate` from the server's received timestamp that I could use later to convert into millisecs and correctly compare it with current's system timestamp, in millisecs as well...

Comment: I do need both formats, `NSDate` and `long long` millisecs

Answer (score 0):

A far as I know, Unix timestamp does not have a timezone field, it takes GMT as standard. If you want to convert your timestamp with time zone to your local time, add or subtract number seconds in difference with GMT. When you get interval from

```
NSTimeInterval unixTime = [[jsonDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPosition, 13)] doubleValue] / 1000;
```

add 3600 seconds to unixTime,

```
unixTime = unixTime+3600.0;//covering the offset. One hour in your case.
```

Now display this time

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTime];
```